# Proof that Harmonic Implies Conformal

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry

How do I show that for some function $u$ that

$$\Delta u = 0 \implies u \> \> \text{is analytic}$$

and assuming $u$ has non-vanishing derivative everywhere, how do I show $u$ is conformal?

I am trying to motivate that functions in the kernel of Laplacian are good candidates for conformal parametrizations.

Comment: This isn't true.

Comment: Which part? Analytic implies conformal? Mathematica claims this this is true.

Comment: if $u : U \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\Delta u = 0$ then $u(z) = Re(f(z))$ where $f(z)$ is holomorphic, and hence $f(z)$ and $u(z)$ are respectively complex and real analytic. The proof should be with the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) (the real part of the Cauchy integral formula).

Comment: Analytic implies conformal when you're talking about _complex-analytic_ functions $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.  It sounds like instead you're talking about a _real-analytic_ function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey : what means conformal exactly ? that $f(z)$ preserves the angles locally ? i.e. that $f(a+z) - f(a) = z f'(a) + o(|z|)$  (with $f'(a) \ne 0$) ? then yes this is exactly the definition of holomorphic (= complex analytic) except for the $f'(a) \ne 0$ part, many harmonic functions are not holomorphic, and many real analytic functions are not harmonic nor holormophic.